# How to allow Cell edit in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a dataGrid which is filled from XML file.
All the value in the file are displayed well.
the problem that i added some others column to my DataGrid and i need to let user
edit the content of those column.
When i tried the edit the content nothing is appeared it s always blank.

Here is my DataGrid Xaml:

```
  <DataGrid 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Elements[Parameter]}"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="Auto" 
        Name="DataGridParamScenarios" Grid.Row="1" MaxHeight ="250"
        Block.TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment =" Stretch"   HorizontalContentAlignment ="Stretch"
        Background="WhiteSmoke" RowBackground="LightYellow"
        AlternatingRowBackground="LightBlue" RowHeight="30" CanUserAddRows="False"
        SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedParameter, Mode=TwoWay}"
        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
        CurrentCellChanged ="DataGridParamScenarios_CurrentCellChanged">

           <DataGrid.Columns>
               
              <DataGridTextColumn 
                Header="Name" IsReadOnly ="True"
                Binding="{Binding Path=Element[Name].Value}" Width ="*"/>
              <DataGridTextColumn 
                Header="Category" 
                Binding="{Binding Path=Element[Category].Value}" Width ="Auto" IsReadOnly="True"/>
              <DataGridTextColumn 
                Header="Value" 
                Binding="{Binding Path=Element[Value].Value}" Width ="*" IsReadOnly="False"/>
              <DataGridTextColumn 
                Header="Unit" 
                Binding="{Binding Path=Element[Unit].Value}" Width ="*" IsReadOnly="False" />
              <DataGridTextColumn 
                Header="Min" Width ="*" IsReadOnly="False"/>
              <DataGridTextColumn 
                Header="Max" Width ="*" IsReadOnly="False"/>
                    
                </DataGrid.Columns>

        </DataGrid>
```

The column which i need to edit are Min and Max.
Any help plz.

## EDIT

i binded the last two Column to local variables but as always nothing appears

```
 <DataGridTextColumn 
                Header="Min" 
                Binding="{Binding Path= MinValue}"
                Width ="*" IsReadOnly="False"/>
 <DataGridTextColumn 
                Header="Max" 
                Binding="{Binding Path= MaxValue}"
                Width ="*" IsReadOnly="False"/>
```

here is the code behind:

```
 public partial class Scenarios : Window
{

    string MinValue = "0";
    string MaxValue = "20";
 public Scenarios()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var xml = XDocument.Load(XmlPath).Root;
        DataGridParamScenarios.DataContext = xml;
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the DataGridTextColumns linked to for binding? I see the first four have binding, why don't you link the last two up to a binding?

Comment: if u can see i modified it but nothing happenes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF can't bind directly to local variables. You have to wrap `MinValue` and `MaxValue` in properties.